# get a value from an object react native

Tags: react-native

I have an object which has the following attributes. I want to show the `serialNumber` in `task array` to show in a `Text` element.

```
Data Object {
  "actionTime": null,
  "arrivedAt": null,
  "callPerson": null,
  "category": null,
  "contactNo": "0",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55",
  "custName1": null,
  "custName2": null,
  "geoLocation": null,
  "id": 1,
  "location": null,
  "remark": null,
  "repeat": null,
  "tasks": Array [
    Object {
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": null,
      "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
      "product": "PRINTER",
      "remark": "paper jam",
      "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
      "status": null,
      "topic": "21080295T210",
      "ttId": 27226,
      "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
    },
  ],
  "topic": null,
}
```

tried following but it doesn't show anything on the App.

```
let item = dataOBJ.tasks
console.log("PSerial :",PSerial)
```

> PSerial : 451444HH1N1GT

```
console.log("iitem :",item)
```

> iitem : Array [   Object {
> "completed": false,
> "createdAt": null,
> "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
> "product": "PRINTER",
> "remark": "paper jam",
> "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
> "status": null,
> "topic": "21080295T210",
> "ttId": 27226,
> "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",   }, ]

```
const warranty = item.filter(function(item){
    return item.serialNumber == PSerial;
}).map(function({warrantyStatus}){
    return{warrantyStatus};
});
```

I want to show in `<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.warrantyStatus}</Text>`

Comment: `tasks` is an array of objects, try `dataOBJ.tasks[0]`

Comment: @AhmCho at where in the code?

Comment: sometimes `item : Array [ Object]` might be multiple objects, so what would be the solution?

Comment: Then I would suggest simply iterating over `dataOBJ.tasks` using `map` and rendering `Text` component(s). Something like this:
`dataOBJ.tasks.filter(function(item){
    return item.serialNumber == PSerial;
}).map((task,index) => {
                return (
                <Text key={index} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{task.warrantyStatus}</Text>
           )}`

Comment: can you put this an answer please

Comment: No problem, did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you'll have multiple objects inside your `tasks` object, you could
use logic from your `warranty` function as follows:

```
item.filter(function(item){
    return item.serialNumber == PSerial;
}).map((task,index) => {
   return(
      <Text
         key={index}
         style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
      >{task.warrantyStatus}</Text>
)})
```